# mysql Does not Use All Columns of Index

Tags: mysql

I have an index with 6 columns. But MySQL will never use the entire index. It will only use a prefix.

```
CREATE TABLE TestChannelData
(
    hostId          MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    sessionId       MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    sessionFragment TINYINT   UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    id              INT       UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    vcid            INT       UNSIGNED NULL,
    dssId           SMALLINT  UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE TestChannelValue
(
    hostId          MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    sessionId       MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    sessionFragment TINYINT   UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    id              INT       UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ertCoarse       INT      UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ertFine         INT      UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE TestChannelValue
    ADD KEY reverseIndex(hostId, sessionId, sessionFragment, id),
    ADD KEY ertReverseIndex(ertCoarse, ertFine, hostId, sessionId, sessionFragment, id);

ALTER TABLE TestChannelValue
ADD KEY reverseErtIndex(hostId, sessionId, sessionFragment, id, ertCoarse, ertFine);
```

The query:

```
SELECT cv.sessionId, cv.hostId, cv.sessionFragment,
     cd.dssId, cd.vcid,
     cv.ertCoarse, cv.ertFine
     FROM TestChannelData AS cd
     STRAIGHT_JOIN TestChannelValue AS cv USE INDEX (ertReverseIndex)
     ON ((cv.sessionId       = cd.sessionId)       AND
         (cv.hostId          = cd.hostId)          AND
         (cv.sessionFragment = cd.sessionFragment) AND
         (cv.id              = cd.id))
     WHERE
        (
            (cv.ertCoarse > 0) AND
            ((cv.ertCoarse < 2000) OR ((cv.ertCoarse = 2000) AND (cv.ertFine = 0)))
        )
```

Explain extended shows that the indes is used, but the key_len is just 8 instead of the desired 19. If I force the index instead to reverseErtIndex, the key_ln is 11.

If I replace the comparisons against the ert columns with just equality,the key_len is 19.

Why will MySQL not use the entire index?

Comment: sometimes mysql will decide that it's more efficient to ignore a key and do a table scan. in any case, you're somewhat over-indexing. if a field is involved in 2+ indexes, maybe it's better to just index it separately.

Comment: MySQL 5.5.15-log. Replacing USE with FORCE does not alter behavior.

Comment: I get the same thing on a MUCH larger database. The query plan shows that ths index is used,just not all of it. The dual indexes are just to test for time-first or time-last, i wouldn't have all of them in the real DB. But it appears that MySQL will either use the columns that use equality, or the columns that use comparisons, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

The key_len of 11 (for reverseErtIndex) corresponds to the columns in the JOIN predicates ( 3 + 3 + 1 + 4 ). Only those columns are needed to locate matching rows. Likely, the EXPLAIN output shows MySQL is using a **`ref`** join operation (shown in the `type` column).

When you modify the query, so that the predicates in the `WHERE` clause are all equality conditions, then the **`ref`** join operation can be extended to those other columns, so you get a longer key_len in the EXPLAIN output.

For inequality comparisons on indexed columns, MySQL does not use a **`ref`** operation, but it can use a **`range`** operation. Likely, MySQL is preferring the **`ref`** operation on a shorter key prefix over a **`range`** operation on a longer key prefix.

---

If MySQL uses the `ertReverseIndex` index, we expect the key_len to be 8, for the `range` operations, based on the predicates in the `WHERE` clause. (If you were to remove the predicate on the `ertFine` column, we'd expect key_len to be reported as 4 in the EXPLAIN output.)

Whether or not MySQL is referencing (i.e. "using") any other columns from the index to satisfy the query, that would be reflected by the presence/absence of "**`Using index`**" in the Extra column of the EXPLAIN output. If that's present, then we know it's a covering index for the query, and that MySQL is not referencing blocks from the underlying table.

---

Bottom line, you've got a combination of equality and inequality predicates. MySQL can use a **`ref`** (or **`equal_ref`**) operation for equality conditions, but not inequality conditions. For inequalities, MySQL can use a **`range`** operation.